# does cocos2d-android-1 compatible with latest cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I start porting my apps to android from ios.  My apps were developed using cocos2d-iphone 1.0 version.  I'd like to know cocos2d-x or cocos2d-andriod-1 compatible with cocos2d-iphone 1.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No / Not really.

First of all the iphone version uses Objective-C and the Android version uses Java as the underlying programming language. That makes them incompatible from a language perspective.

As far as features and stability are concerned, cocos2d is a moving target and the android builds as well as practically any other cocos2d engine are lagging far behind cocos2d-iphone. Maybe with the exception of cocos2d-x whose developers make an effort to be as close to cocos2d-iphone as possible, feature-wise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am looking at cocos2d-x with Android now.  I still could not make it run on Eclipse.  The documents are very confusing.  :(